# Minimum Coin Change Problem(Top-Down Approach)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have coded a top-down approach to solve the famous [minimum coin change problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-number-of-coins-that-make-a-change/) as shown in the code below. But the code runs into segmentation fault when the money is close to 44000. I have three varieties of coin {1,4,5}. I don't know what is going on? I suspect I am running out of stack memory. But 44000 seems a small value. So, I tested it on an online [IDE](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/LxdtEC6Pyg). But it seems to works perfectly there. I am running my code on NetBeans 8.2(on a laptop of 8GB RAM). Please help me
Following is the snippet of my function:

```
//A top-down approach
int change_tpd(int m, vector<int>&coins, vector<int>&dp)
{
    if(dp[m]!=-1)
        return dp[m];
    else if(m==0)
        dp[m] = 0;
    else
    {
        int x = INT_MAX;
        for(int i=0;i<coins.size();++i)
        {
            if(m-coins[i]>=0)
                x = min(x,change_tpd(m-coins[i],coins,dp));
        }
        dp[m] = 1+x;
    }
    return dp[m];
}
```

Comment: Forgive me but it is a bit ironic that your are using a dynamic programing array (dp) yet solving the problem top down instead of bottom up as usually done in dynamic programing. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: In such a situation, to analyse what is happining, you could try to count the number of times the function is called, and display it for different values of input.

Comment: Change the stack size setting in your IDE to something larger? Perhaps netbeans uses a particularly low default stack size -- it would be worth your while investigating this if you wish to use NetBeans.

Comment: @Yonlif There is no irony there.  Both top down and bottom up are dynamic programming.  You see more written about bottom up because it is harder to learn, and can be more memory efficient.  But if you're actually faced with a problem on a time constraint and aren't positive how to do it, you would be well-advised to do top down first.  Passing in the data structure to be memoized is just an implementation detail.  (Lets you know when you can free memory up.)

Comment: @btilly You are correct, sorry. But a top down approach is mentioned might be less memory efficient and since the problem is **probably** stack overflow so transforming it to bottom up can be a good call.

Comment: @Yonlif Exactly, I find bottom-up approach a bit less intuitive and difficult to come up with. That's why, I was trying to solve all DP Problems with recursion and converting them to memoization. After getting comfortable with both, I do it with Bottom-up Approach. But yeah, I think there was a some issue with my NetBeans.

Comment: @Yonlif True.  And yes, bottom up is better for stack overflow limits.  Which tend to be surprisingly small in threaded languages like Java.  (Because each thread gets its own stack and they add up.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could reduce the depth of the search tree by doing something like this:

Say that you have a set C = {c1, ..., cn} of N coins sorted by decreasing order of their values, with respective weights X = {x1, ..., xn}

We are trying to minimize Sum_{1<=i<=N}{xi} where Prod_{1<=i<=N}{ci*xi} = V

Given that we are trying to minimum the sum of xi, any solution of form S=...+cixi+...+cjxj+... where xj>=ci and i<j is dominated by a solution of form S'=...+ci(xi+cj)+...+cj(xj-ci)+...

By extention the form of a dominant solution is xj<(ci-1) for every 1<=i<j<=N, and even more restrictive xj<(ci/gcd(ci,cj))-1 for every 1<=i<j<=N (does anyone get the reference for this or for anything else below?)

We obtain that way the upper bound vector U of X with xi<=ui for every 1<=i<=N.
In vector U, u1 is infinite and all the others values are bounded; as the result we can easily compute the maximum value Z = \Sum_{2<=i<=N}{ci*ui} we can make without using any coin c1 for a dominant solution

By extension the resolution of V>Z can be reduce to the resolution of V' = V - ip((V-Z+c1-1)/c1)*c1 with ip(r) the integer part of r, and by increasing the result by ip((V-Z+c1-1)/c1).

In your instance, C = {5, 4, 1}, Z = 19;
V = 44000 > Z, V' = 44000 - ip((44000-17)/5)*5 = 15, and the result is incremented by 8797

This also makes the DP array way smaller.